# How to play audio from local folder in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Please can some one show me or direct me step by step on How to play audio from local folder in xamarin forms for android and iOS Project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put there mp3 in these folders , Android Assets en iOS Recourses

[image]

Property

[image]

And iOS property
[image]

Install this - pluging Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer

To play in a Button.Clicked

> var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
> player.Load("Drup.mp3");
> player.Play();

Comment: I have put the mp3 in these folders: Android Assets and iOS Recourses like you said and I installed the Plugin. But Sorry I'm learning. pls. Show me the example on how to display my code in PlayPage.xaml or PlayPage.xaml.cs or in another way to complete the question. thank you for your response.

Comment: the repo for SimpleAudioPlayer contains a complete example app

Comment: @Jason, Ok  show me the link.

Comment: you can't google it?  https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/tree/master/SimpleAudioPlayer/Samples

Comment: @Jason, I have created the same project in order to test the Code, as the above link, but when i navigate to click on the **Shared library audio demo Page** it shows me: **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'** but the second link were played successfully. Please i need your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: I made a simpel example with a button https://github.com/borisoprit/Music

Comment: @BasH This is not working

Comment: Are You recreate this example or getting an error running this . Maybe show some code because this is hard for every one to help You .

Comment: I'm getting an error running the code:

Comment: It's ok for now. Thank you all for your contributions

Comment: The link is working now https://github.com/borisoprit/Music